# SELECT LEFT vs SUBSTR

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
WITH processed_users 
     AS (SELECT LEFT(u.phone_country, 2) AS short_phone_country, 
                u.id 
         FROM   users u) 
SELECT t.user_id, 
       t.merchant_country, 
       Sum(t.amount / fx.rate / Power(10, cd.exponent)) AS amount 
FROM   transactions t 
       JOIN fx_rates fx 
         ON ( fx.ccy = t.currency 
              AND fx.base_ccy = 'EUR' ) 
       JOIN currency_details cd 
         ON cd.currency = t.currency 
       JOIN processed_users pu 
         ON pu.id = t.user_id 
WHERE  t.source = 'GAIA' 
       AND pu.short_phone_country = t.merchant_country 
GROUP  BY t.user_id, 
          t.merchant_country 
ORDER  BY amount DESC;
```

could someone explain in detailed (if possible) what is wrong with the first part (SELECT LEFT(...

Comment: What do you mean "what is wrong"?

Comment: There is no LEFT() function in SQLite. Use substr()

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite does not support `LEFT`

```
 SELECT LEFT(u.phone_country, 2) AS short_phone_country
 <=> 
 SELECT SUBSTR(u.phone_country, 1, 2) AS short_phone_country
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not support `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` functions on strings.  The functions that SQLite does support are clearly in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

`LEFT(x, 2)` is easily replaced with `SUBSTR(x, 1, 2)`.

`RIGHT(x, 2)` is `SUBSTR(x, -2)`.